# div is not stretching as the content grows

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 divs (left panel, center and footer). Everything aligned nicely, but whenever the content in the center div grows, I want the center div to stretch to include all it's content.

```
    <div class="parent">
    <!-- Header starts-->
    <div class="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <!--span class="indent"><img src="img/fdm-logo.png"/><span-->
            <h1 class="indent">
                Trading platform
                <h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Header ends-->

    <!-- Left panel starts-->
    <div class="leftPanel">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
                <li class='active'><a>User</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Add User</a></li>
                        <li><a>Update User</a></li>
                        <li><a>Delete User</a></li>
                        <li><a>Ban User</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </li>
                <li><a>View Service Request</a></li>
                <li><a>About us</a></li>
                <li class='last'><a>Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left panel ends-->

    <!-- Login panel starts-->
    <div class="contentPanel">
        <div id="form_wrapper" class="form_wrapper">
            <form class="login active" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
                method="post">
                <h3>Add/ Update User</h3>
                <span id="msgError" class="error">This is an error</span> Username:
                <input id="uName" type="text" maxlength="30" /> Password: <input
                    id="pwd" type="password" maxlength="30" /> Confirm Password: <input
                    id="cPwd" type="password" maxlength="30" /> Full Name: <input
                    id="fName" type="text" maxlength="30" /> 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> 
                    User Role: 
                    <select name="role">
                        <option value="volvo">Share Holder</option>
                        <option value="saab">Broker</option>
                        <option value="fiat">System Admin</option>
                    </select>
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                <div class="bottom">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Login panel ends -->

    <!-- Footer starts -->
    <div class="footer clear">
        <p class="indent copyright">
            Copyright &copy; FDM Group 2014<br />
            <br /> By using this site you agree we can set and use cookies<br />
            For details of these cookies and how to disable them, <a
                href="http://www.fdmgroup.com/cookie-policy/">click to read our
                cookie policy</a><br />
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer ends -->
</div>
```

***MY CODE IN FIDDLE:***
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sas/8vp5ufhy/)

But in my page the content is displayed out side of the center div for some reason.

[image: screen shot]

Why and how do I fix this prob. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-3-column.htm is having good example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the leftPanel, contentPanel and footerPanelwith another div then style that div to have the samebackground as your leftPanel

```
<div class="mainPanel">
```

CSS

```
.mainPanel {
    background-color:#151515;
}
```

See here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vp5ufhy/7/)

Also your H1 tag isn't closed properly and you have and extra /li tag

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `height` property for class `contentPanel`, you can use `min-height` property. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c7h2pm00/)

```
.contentPanel {
    /*height:70%;*/
    min-height:70%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:75%;
}
```

Hope that this will solve your problem.

Comment: It does solve the problem with center div, but the left panel doesn't seems to match the height of center panel. Any idea on how to match them both on size?

Comment: For making the left panel height fit to the center div, you have to give height according to the center div height. ie, you have to set height as fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your fiddle to [get solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8vp5ufhy/4/)

I have created a wrapper div which should consist of left-panel and contentpanel

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="leftPanel">
   </div>

   <div class="contentPanel">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   display:table;
}

.contentPanel {
   display:table-cell;
}

.leftPanel {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your left-panel and center in one div. similar to wrapper.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: "This does not provide an answer to the question"... I think it is the answer for his/her question!

Comment: please share some relevant code / css instead of putting just comment/explanation. You can check others posted answer also.

Comment: A little bit of code wouldn't hurt to help push the OP in the right direction... even if this is the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set **position:absolute** , **width:auto** & **height:auto** for the div.

```
.parent{
    position:absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont Use fixed height for Content Div
    .contentPanel {
          float: left;
          /*height: 70%;*/
          position: relative;
          width: 75%;
      }

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in another `<div>`

```
<div> ***ADD THIS****
        <div class="leftPanel">
            <div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                    <li class='active'><a>User</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Add User</a></li>
                            <li><a>Update User</a></li>
                            <li><a>Delete User</a></li>
                            <li><a>Ban User</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>View Service Request</a></li>
                    <li><a>About us</a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a>Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left panel ends-->

        <!-- Login panel starts-->
        <div class="contentPanel">
            <div id="form_wrapper" class="form_wrapper">
                <form class="login active" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
                    method="post">
                    <h3>Add/ Update User</h3>
                    <span id="msgError" class="error">This is an error</span> Username:
                    <input id="uName" type="text" maxlength="30" /> Password: <input
                        id="pwd" type="password" maxlength="30" /> Confirm Password: <input
                        id="cPwd" type="password" maxlength="30" /> Full Name: <input
                        id="fName" type="text" maxlength="30" /> 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> 
                        User Role: 
                        <select name="role">
                            <option value="volvo">Share Holder</option>
                            <option value="saab">Broker</option>
                            <option value="fiat">System Admin</option>
                        </select>
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                        Funds: <input id="funds"type="text" maxlength="30" /> User Role: 
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```